# Can I turn off Google Drive's history?

Tags: google-drive

I'm using Google Drive and I have a very limited amount of data, near 500 Mega Bytes.
However, I don't really need Google to take history of those files, as I'm the only person working on them, and I've never gone back to the earlier versions, never.

So, I went into Drive's settings, but seems that there is no option to disable document history. Is there any way to get that?

Comment: As far as I know, the document history does not use your allotted space.

Comment: And, apparently, history is only available for Google Drive native files, which take up very little space anyway. No, there is not currently a way to turn off the revision history.

Comment: @ale, I can't find anywhere in Google's documentation that says this. Can you share a link?

Answer (score 1):

Can't seem to turn it off, but you can delete old versions. They may have added this feature recently. Click on the file, then click on the 3 dots at the top-right (More actions), then click on "Manage versions". From there you can permanently delete one or more of the older versions. It states each version is removed automatically after 30 days, but this doesn't seem to be the case, I had versions going back months. Seems to work for me, cleared a GB of old versions!

Comment: Is there any easy way to delete old versions of all files, going to files one at a time is cumbersome